# in or on the following business Day

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I have been trying to find a quick answer of this, but my google searches didn't get me anywhere. I'm confused about using in or on in the following sentence.

We will return your call **in** the following business Day

or

We will return your call **on** the following business Day

Thank you

Comment: Please provide the context, as either construction can be acceptable depending on where and how it is used.

Comment: I have provided the context, thanks for your input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is "on the following business day".  
The general rule: When you have a when-indication that contains the word "day" you use on:   
on Monday, on the next day, on the following day, on Christmas Day. You can drop "on"
and say shorter: the next day, the following day. "on" is often dropped at the beginning or end of a sentence.